# Calculated Column formula for contains

Tags: list, calculated-column

What if I need a "contains" command instead of an `=` ?

`=IF([Package Status]="Further Clarification","Yes","No")`

Comment: Learn all the available Functions in SP: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 6):

You could try the **FIND** formula for this one.

e.g. Check if "ABC" contains "A"

```
=FIND("A",[Column1])
```

For more details, check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your given formula to get the desired result:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Further Clarification",[Package Status])),"No","Yes")
```

**Explanation:** Above formula will first find the "Further Clarification" in the column called "Package Status". If this find results in an error (that is, the String is not in the column/data does not exist) it will return "No". Otherwise, the String exists in the column, so it returns "Yes".

Ask me for further information.

Comment: Have you tried above solution given in my answer? is that works for you?